# Why do we need two different storage accounts for Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Is there any side effect of using same storage connection string for both purposes?

1. AzureWebJobsDashboard
2. AzureWebJobsStorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any side effect of using same storage connection string for both purposes?

Short answer is **no**, you could use the same storage connection for them. Based on my understanding is that Webjob allow use to use different storages to save the Webjob dashboard and Webjob information. We could get more information about it from [AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/03/14/azure-webjob-logs-demystified/)

> **AzureWebJobsDashboard**
>
> This storage account is primarily used by Azure WebJob SDK to store logs from the WebJobs Dashboard. This connection string is optional and is required only if you are planning to use the dashboard for monitoring WebJobs.
>
> The WebJob runtime creates two containers under this storage account with the names ‘azure-webjobs-dashboard’ and ‘azure-jobs-host-archive’. The azure-webJobs-dashboard container is used by the WebJob dashboard to store host and execution endpoint (function) details. Azure-jobs-host-archive is used as an archive for execution logs.
>
> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> AzureWebJobsStorage should point to a storage account which will be primarily used for logging. WebJob runtime creates two containers in this storage account with the names ‘azure-jobs-host-output’ and ‘azure-webjobs-host’. If you point AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage  at two different storage accounts, you will notice that these two containers are duplicated in both the storage accounts.